# node js easy rtc connection use https

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, video-streaming, easyrtc

i use easyrtc
[EasyRtc Github](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc)

I use IFRAME streaming load my web page PHP. Everything was fine when my site was protocol HTTP. Now I changed the HTTP connection to HTTPS, connection beginning not to work. 
Node js installed on the same server, I connect to it via ip, without the https protocol. How can I set up the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a fake certificate and private keys when you create server using https module, like

```
var webServer = https.createServer({key: privateKey, cert: certificate}, httpApp).listen(8000);
```

Happy coding